Linking fails when compiling Android app with Graalvm
I have been trying to compile a simple HelloWorld app with gluon on Linux for Android but have been experiencing problems.  I have made some progress after installing GCC as per the suggestion on https://simply-how.com/fix-graalvm-native-image-compilation-issues.  However I am still unable to link the project.  I get an error: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 cannot be used against symbol 'graalVM'; recompile with -fPIC. I am using graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final and gradle 7.5.1 to compile the code. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?
I have checked the process link log as per help output and it seems to be failing on the Android NDK compiler clang++. I have tried running the commands in the process log and it points to the correct path for clang in the ndk but still produces the same error.  I have also tried compiling with the new version of the gluon graalvm, graalvm-java23-linux-amd64-gluon-23+25.1-dev but this does not even get past the compilation step.

Have you tried building the HelloFX sample from https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples? Does that work for you? It should work with either plugin GluonFX 1.0.23 and graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final, or with GluonFX 1.0.24 and graalvm-java23-linux-amd64-gluon-23+25.1-dev. If it doesn't, post the logs you get.

I have tried compiling the sample HelloFX with Gluon 1.0.23 and it gives an error...   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project hellofx: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]

Make sure your JAVA_HOME points to JDK 21 or greater.

Hi.  I have tried recompiling with JAVA_HOME set to graalvm-java23-linux-amd64-gluon-23+25.1-dev.  This does seem to get a bit further but still returns an exception when I run from the desktop with mvn gluonfx:run.  I have used Maven 3.8.6 to compile the example.  I was compiling my own HelloWorld app width Gradle 7.5.1 and this does build and run on the desktop but not nativeBuild.

I have now managed to build the maven project, it seems that it could not find the resources.  I can now run and create a native-image but am still struggling to link the APK.  I think it is not seeing my android-sdk.

Hi I have finally managed to link my build and compile an APK but it does not work on my target device.  I have filled in keystore details to sign the APK, do I need to do anything else before it will work on an Android device?

Actually I think it is to do with the Android API Level as it works on a newer device
